# How do I control the icon set for 20.04?

Tags: icons, 20.04

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 on my 2 computers.

To my surprise the icon sets are different. The second image shows icons quite similar to 18.04. (The screen shot icon has changed from 18.04, so they are not identical.)

I don't remember ever trying to interfere with the Ubuntu defaults, so I am surprised at the difference. One thing I do remember from the past is looking at X11 and Wayland, so I thought that may be the difference?

```
ilan@ilan-AM1M-S2H:~$ loginctl
SESSION  UID USER SEAT  TTY 
  2 1000 ilan seat0 tty2

1 sessions listed.
ilan@ilan-AM1M-S2H:~$ loginctl show-session 2 -p Type
Type=x11
ilan@ilan-AM1M-S2H:~$
```

I got the same results on both systems, so that isn't the cause.

Question:

What is the cause of the difference and how do I make my desktop be the same as my laptop?

[image: desktop]
[image: laptop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install gnome-tweaks from software center or from command line:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

In the Appearance tab on the left you will find a windows menu with the list of all the icon set in your system. the icon set in your first screenshot is the most recent version of Yaru icon theme. Play with the option to set the appearance of your system as you wish.

Comment: On neither computer was tweaks installed. So something I did in the past must have had some lasting effects. I put tweaks on the desktop and tried the default Adwita set. That was preferable to Yaru, but not equal to what is on the laptop. Near the bottom of the list are 5-6 equivalent sets. Among them I chose Ubuntu-mono-light.  I had to change Applications as well to get the proper trash bin. Afterwards I could change the Applications back to Yaru and nothing changed back again. So the main thing to change is Icons, but Applications also has an effect. Thanks.